# Return Null when json keys are null

Tags: postgresql

I have message table that has columns like so
Client:

| id | created_by_agent_id | created_by_agent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | null |

I have a select query that gets the messages with the agent/client that has created it.

```
SELECT 
id,
json_build_object(
'id', agent.id,
'firstName', agent.first_name,
) AS "createdByAgent",
json_build_object(
'id', client.id,
'firstName', client.first_name,
) AS "createdByClient"
FROM message 
LEFT JOIN agent
ON message.created_by_agent_id = agent.id
LEFT JOIN client
ON message.created_by_client_id = client.id
WHERE id = 10
```

The issue is that when theres no client/agent the resulting json will like like this:

```
{"id" : null, "firstName" : null, "lastName" : null, "avatarLink" : null}
```

How can return value `null` for createdByClient/createdByAgent the keys instead?

Comment: Maybe a `CASE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`CASE ... END`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case/) to do a IF before showing data, like that:

```
SELECT 
id,
CASE
  WHEN agent.first_name is null THEN null
  ELSE json_build_object(
    'id', agent.id,
    'firstName', agent.first_name,
  )
END AS createdByAgent,
CASE
  WHEN client.first_name is null THEN null
  ELSE json_build_object(
    'id', client.id,
    'firstName', client.first_name,
  )
END AS createdByClient
FROM message 
LEFT JOIN agent ON message.created_by_agent_id = agent.id
LEFT JOIN client ON message.created_by_client_id = client.id
WHERE id = 10
```

Obviously, you can add multiple arguments into the `WHEN` cause to check if the id is null too for example